# How can I get some basic GNU utilities on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I'm specifically looking for `du`, but really, I want the usual suite of command line power tools. Which package contains those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coreutils` provides `du` and other CLI tools.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dpkg -S du` I discovered that there is a copy of `du` in the Cydia libexec folder. It's not quite as nice as finding it in /bin, but it'll serve my purposes nicely. The general question is still open, though; where can I find awk, sed, and so on?

Comment: The full path to the `du` in the Cydia libexec folder: `/usr/libexec/cydia/du`